# What does doing a tensor network contraction "for bond dimension k" mean?

Tags: tensor-rank

I’m a tensor-network newbie and am working through Bridgeman and Chubb’s “Hand-waving and Interpretive Dance: An Introductory Course on Tensor Networks” (arXiv:1603.03039v4).

At the end of Chapter 1, Problem #3 says “Calculate the contraction of the tensor network in Eq. (1.19) for bond dimension 3 …” I thought the dimension in which a contraction between two tensors would happen is determined by the set of overlapping indices. What does “contracting for bond dimension x” mean for tensor networks?

Comment: In this particular case, I think they're asking you to do the contraction for the specified tensor network when all the bonds have dimension 3 (which would indeed corresponding to counting 3-colorings, as they mention).

Comment: Is it more accurate to say the bonds have maximum dimension 3?  Thank you!

Comment: In this particular case, I believe they want all the bonds to have dimension exactly 3. The idea is: the 3 choices coming out of a vertex in the original graph (e-tensor in the tensor network) correspond to the 3 choices of color. The e-tensor enforces that all the colors coming out of the same vertex are the same. The n-tensors then enforce that the color of one vertex in the original graph differs from the color of its neighboring vertices.